# Cities still occupied by ally

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I had an ally during a war, and he helped me siege some cities (his army was greater than mine).  Despite us being allies and me winning the war and the county, the county still has the "siege lines", and the mouseover says "Cities 1 and 2: Occupied by ally".  How do I get my cities back?

Comment: The cities were occupied both before and after the end of the war, and in both cases they were considered to have been occupied by your ally?

Comment: Is he still your ally? Are you at war (any war)? Are the holdings definitely yours?

Comment: @SMeznaric - yes to both questions.

Comment: @Nix - Yes, he is still my ally.  No, I'm no longer at war.  And the holdings are definitely mine.

Comment: Was your ally in a separate war?

Comment: @SMeznaric If he were, then OP surely wouldn't be able to demand the counties? Also, any changes in ownership cancels any other dispute, unless I'm gravely mistaken (perhaps some edge cases).

Comment: It's possible if the ally occupied only some but not all holdings of the county. I believe you get unoccupied enemy holdings when you sign peace.

Comment: This happened to me as well but in those cases the occupying nation was in a seperate war. E.g. I am attacking King of Bavaria for Austria. Meanwhile Hungarians are also attacking Bavaria for lets say for Linz in austria. While I occupied enough territories to enforce peace, Hungarians had occupied city of Linz in Austria. I got whole austria but linz remained occupied by hungarians, which went to either Bavarians or Hungarians depending on their peace deal.